# Could another process control the pyqt5 widget in the main process when using multiprocessing?

Tags: python, opencv, multiprocessing, pyqt5

I am working on a software that could play several videos simultaneously and assemble them in a single interface. As the result of the existence of GIL which hinders the efficiency of threads, I decided to use one process for each video being played.  Here are my **simplified** codes.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import threading
import cv2
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import threading

class Main_UI(QtWidgets.QMainWindow)
       def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()
          self.label_screen1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)   # used for display
          self.label_screen2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)   # used for display
          self.img_q1=mp.Queue(maxsize=2)      # a queue used as frame channel
          self.img_q2=mp.Queue(maxsize=2)      # a queue used as frame channel
          #create a process to read videos, it sends frames to the queue1
          self.img_fetcher1= mp.Process(target=play,args = (self.img_q1,"xxx/xxx.mp4"))
          self.img_fetcher1.start()
          #create a process to read videos, it sends frames to the queue2
          self.img_fetcher2= mp.Process(target=play,args = (self.img_q2,"yyy/yyy.mp4"))
          self.img_fetcher2.start()

          #create a thread to keep displaying the images received from the queue1 onto the label1
          self.video_thread1 = threading.Thread(target=self.display)
          self.video_thread1.start()
          #create a thread to keep displaying the images received from the queue2 onto the label2
          self.video_thread2 = threading.Thread(target=self.display)
          self.video_thread2.start()

       def display(self):
            while True:
                if not self.result_img_q.empty():
                    show=self.result_img_q.get()
                    showImage = QImage(show.data, show.shape[1], show.shape[0],
                                   QImage.Format_RGB888)  
                    self.label_screen.setScaledContents(True)
                    self.label_screen.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(showImage))   #display on the label




def play(img_q,video_path):     # this method run as a process
    videocap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    while True:
        flag, frame = videocap.read()
        if flag:   
                frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  
                time.sleep(0.02)
                img_q.put(frame)            #send the frame to the queue
```

The code works fine， but I found that the speed is not that satisfying. I guess it's partly because of the GIL,  2 threads cannot display images onto labels separately and simultaneously, for one have to wait for the another. I wonder whether it is possible to display an image onto a label by process 'img_fetcher' directly.  Just like passing a shared value to a process from the main process, and change the value in that process.

Could anyone please tell me how to solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Okay I am not fully understanding your question -- (1) You cannot use a QtWidget any where but within the Main Event Thread period end of story (2) The GIL only applies to Threads I believe and not to Multiprocessing which you need for each new QtWidget containing process that you wish to run (3) If you are experiencing lag and you are properly using Multiprocessing then you are over taxing you system or you only have 1 CPU or basically its a hardware issue  (4) You should not use Python Threads when using Python-Qt you should be using QThread -- or you will have issues

Comment: @Dennis Jensen Thank you for your advice,  and let me try to state my question more clearly .  Main_UI and the threads it creates belong to the main process, and during the initialization of the Main_UI, it also creates two new processes: ' img_fetcher1' and   ' img_fetcher2'.  I just want to know whether  'img_fetcher' could change the state of  widgets  of Main_UI, such as turning on a button.

Comment: @Dennis Jensen just like passing a shared value to a process from the main process, and change the value in that process